# PostgreSQL GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql

I want to return the name of those persons who have the highest salary city-wise. This is my table:

[image: employee table]

I was able to print the highest salary city-wise by using the GROUP BY clause. But how to return the name of those employees also who have the highest salary. I want to return something like this:

[image: targetQuery]. as these persons have the highest salary city-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `rank` window function to rank the employees per city, and then wrap that query with another query to get only the highest one per city:

```sql
SELECT ename, city, salary
FROM   (SELECT ename, city, salary,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rk
        FROM   employee) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I strongly recommend `distinct on` for this purpose:

```
select distinct on (city) e.*
from employee e
order by city, salary desc;
```

`distinct on` is a Postgres extension specifically designed for this type of problem.